# Where to find "Heat deflection temperature" , "Impact resistance Charpy" and "Tensile strength" for a specific brand Filament PLA?

Tags: pla, prusa-i3

I have an MK3S 3D printer, and I use this table as a reference on how to tune my printer for a specific Filament
brand.

https://help.prusa3d.com/en/materials

I am trying to find a few missing parameters for a specific brand Filament PLA in the table.

The missing parameters are listed and shown in the image below.

- Heat deflection temperature
- Impact resistance Charpy
- Tensile strength

[image]

Where is the best place or reference to find such missing data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the Manufacturer offers them, you have to extrapolate from other brands. Most PLAs are very close and hit within 10% of one another.